# What does this code do? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Could you explain what this code does? Is it creating a new object from database? I need to know how this model creating database and how to connect.

```
public class DictionaryValue : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }        
    public DictionaryType Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

internal class DictionaryValueMappings : EntityTypeConfiguration<DictionaryValue>
{
    public DictionaryValueMappings()
    {
        Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(200);
        Property(p => p.Value).IsMaxLength();
        Property(p => p.Description).HasMaxLength(1000);
        Property(p => p.Type).IsRequired();
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> GetList<TResult>(IPager pager, DictionaryType type, string name = null)
{
    using (var context = Context.Read())
    {
        var query = context.Query<DictionaryValue>().AsQueryable();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(name));
        }

        return query
                .Where(p => p.Type == type)
                .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                .Pager(pager)
                .GetResult<TResult>();
    }
}
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you defined DictionaryValue class that tells ef there is a "DictionaryValue" table in my database, DictionaryValueMappings class defines mapping class, this class tells ef context that each property points to which column in DictionaryValue table, this class will add to dbContext modelBinder configuration object

and finally GetList method will returns a list of TResult(that is generic), this method uses DictionaryValue table to load custom settings or anything else from database, for working this method you must implement GetResult and Pager so it can load for example various setting from dictionaries